# Combine MySQL tables and include records with the lowest timestamp

Tags: mysql, join, timestamp, aggregate-functions

I have three tables: 'user', 'user_packages' and 'subscription'. The first one contains user info, the second one contains the package IDs that the user is interested in (user_packages.user = user.ID) and the third one holds all package subscriptions for a user. (subscription.user = user.ID, subscription.package = user_packages.package).

I am making a query on the first table, for example all users in the city of New York. I would like to make a join with the package table to get user packages, which is no problem. However, I also want to include the actual subscriptions, which means where end_date = 0 (subscription not yet ended).

The desired end result is a list with all users in New York, with a way to see if it is a subscriber or not. If a user doesn't have subscriptions, he should still be returned however.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT user.*, sub.user AS subscriber, sub.end_date, userp.package FROM user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_packages userp ON userp.user = user.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscription sub ON sub.user = user.ID
WHERE user.city = 'New York' 
GROUP BY user.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

It will just return all users in New York and if "subscriber" is not NULL, then the user is a subscriber. So far so good, but "subscriber" will also be set for former subscribers (end_date > 0). If end_date > 0 then there must be some way to find out it is not a subscriber.

Things to think about:

- If I include "WHERE (end_date IS NULL OR end_date = 0)", then it will not return the users with ended subscriptions and no active subscriptions anymore
- If the user has both active and ended subscriptions, it should take the active one, not the row it encounters first (because that could be the ended one)

Any help is appreciated!

**[EDIT]**

Here are the specific tables with some sample records and the desired outcome in order to make it all more understandable.

```
user:                                      user_packages:
---------------------------------------    -------------------------
|  ID  |  Name    |   ...  |   City   |    |  ID  | user | package |
---------------------------------------    -------------------------
| 101  |  User A  |   ...  | New York |    |  23  | 101  |   1     |
| 102  |  User B  |   ...  | New York |    |  24  | 101  |   2     |
| 103  |  User C  |   ...  | Miami    |    |  25  | 102  |   1     |
| 104  |  User D  |   ...  | New York |    |  26  | 104  |   1     | 
---------------------------------------    -------------------------

subscriptions:
------------------------------------------------------ 
|  ID  |  user    | package | start_date | end_date   |
------------------------------------------------------ 
|  5   |  101     |   1     | 2014-05-01 | 0000-00-00 |
|  6   |  101     |   2     | 2014-06-09 | 2014-08-31 |
|  7   |  102     |   1     | 2014-06-15 | 0000-00-00 |   
|  8   |  104     |   1     | 2014-07-02 | 2014-08-02 |
-------------------------------------------------------

Desired end result:
------------------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  Name    |   ...  |   City   |  subscriber  |
------------------------------------------------------
| 101  |  User A  |   ...  | New York |    101       |
| 102  |  User B  |   ...  | New York |    102       |
| 104  |  User D  |   ...  | New York |    NULL      | 
------------------------------------------------------
```

User A has one active and one ended subscription, thus subscriber.

User B has one active and no ended subscriptions, thus subscriber.

User C is not in New York, thus not showing up in the results.

User D has no active and one ended subscription, thus not a subscriber.

I hope this clears it up a little!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. I edited my question and I hope it clears it up a little.

Comment: Great. I can only refer you to the comment I made previously.